# Man is trapped for years, begins exercising

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

A man wakes up, wearing only boxer shorts. He is trapped in an environment that is sort of like a fun house, that has a picture of someone that looks a bit like Haile Selassie. Years evidently pass. He lets himself go physically but then gets into shape by doing exercises he sees on a video screen using objects in his environment like books as weights. Time passes. He is shown video of what I assume is his wife and daughter, who plays the cello.

That's what I remember (I saw this on someone's screen (no sound) on an airplane, but fell asleep). Does anyone know what (recent) film this is?

Comment: Do you know how recently this film was out? Could you guess at language (despite not hearing it)? Description of actors/actresses? Location? Any other details at all?

Comment: Airlines often publish the movies they show on the web .... if this was a recent flight, you might just be able to look it up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: Oldboy (2013) - Movie Poster]

That could be ["**Oldboy** (2013)"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1321511/).

> Obsessed with vengeance, a man sets out to find out why he was
>   kidnapped and locked into solitary confinement for 20 years without
>   reason.

[image: Oldboy (2013) - Pic 01]
[image: Oldboy (2013) - Pic 02]

<sup>*~ Stills used are YouTube screenshots*</sup>

Watch the [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKz_AUF0GcU) to confirm.

**Note**: If you're interested, check out the [original](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5L0huBSdIw) as well.

Comment: It must be added that this Old Boy (2013) movie was based on an earlier South Korean version (2003) with exactly the same plot line --- though different ending.  I found the 2003 version way superior to the American 2013 version.  It is possible that the @OurJames was asking about the earlier one.